# Strange issue with 404 error pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a website set up that uses a custom 404 error page. This seems to be working on most pages.

In fact, I have two different error pages that I want to show, and now a third that I just found out about.

This page, which does not exist, shows the correct error page that should be shown if a page cannot be found. This shows the error page as configured in my .htaccess file:
http://www.canadiancommuter.com/wontfindthis.php

This error page is generated from my PHP code if someone tries to access an old article that no longer exists in the database:
http://www.canadiancommuter.com/2334054466-some+old+article.html

However, this link, which will also generate a 404 error, shows a different error page (which usually includes advertising):
http://www.canadiancommuter.com/2012062500-TTC+asks+Ministry+of+Labour+to+treat+CNE+like+Rolling+Stones+concert%2FCaribana.html

I know the reason WHY this URL doesn't work. I purposely added characters to it to cause it to return a 404 error. My problem is that I can't figure out WHERE this other 404 error page is coming from.

It's not in my .htaccess file, the error page from my .htaccess file can be seen in the first link above.

It's not in my code. The only error page generated by the code itself can be seen in the second link above.

The only other places it could come from is my domain registrar, and my web host.

The domain is registered through one registrar, but points to my hosting account with another provider. The registrar says that because I'm just pointing the DNS for my domain to we web host the error page wouldn't come from them, but would come from my web host.

My web host says this error page isn't coming from them, but must be in my code.

I've heavily modified all of the code used for this site, so I'm pretty confident that the error page is not coming from there.

Does anyone have any ideas where I should look for this error page?

(Just a note, I'm not certain the registrar or the web host were entirely sure of what they were talking about, so I haven't ruled out either of them as being the source of this page. However, a thorough look through the administrative consoles for both do not reveal anything to this effect.)

Comment: Also, I want to point out that this is a second website running from the same hosting account as another site of mine. I have never seen these error pages on my other website. The only thing different about both sites, besides the content, is that the domain I'm having the problem with was registered through a different registrar, whereas my other domain is registered through my web hosting provider. Is it possible that this page is coming from my domain registrar? (Even though they are basically just pointing my domain to my web host?)

Comment: Another thing I wanted to add, is that this only happens on a part of the site where the urls are re-written by apache. On other parts of the site a % in the url causes a "400 bad request" error, but in the area that gets re-written it shows a 404 error page, that I cannot find the location of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is absolutely from your host provider!!**

When %2F is given in url, nginx cannot handle that as an error (this might be a bug!) and it displays your host's default error page, you can see the same error on other websites hosted on the same server as your site:

- http://aias-uic.org/not-found.html
- http://halfdrawn.com/not-found.html
- http://flyingmantis.com/not%2Ffound.html
- ...

and there are many other websites on the same server as your site! (you can check their IP to be sure)

The last one uses custom error page, so with %2F the *mysterious* error page is shown!

You can also disable your custom error pages for a while and you will probably get the mysterious error page!

Comment: After some research I believe you are correct. 

The host, iPage, actually has an option if you choose not to set up custom error pages. There's an option to disable ads on your "non-custom error pages". 

So even with custom error pages set up, and the ads disabled, this specific error page remains the same, with the ads. I am now in a discussion with the host to see if there is any way they'll remove the ads from their generic error pages. Since all of their customers are paying customers it doesn't seem right to show ads on generic pages. On the others, where they can be disabled, fine.

Comment: I have one other question, which is rather simple. When you go to the third link in my original post, and get the default error page, is there advertising on it? I'm trying to determine if the ads that are shown are put there by my host, or possible some sort of adware on my computer doing it.

Comment: @SherwinFlight - When I go to that page, I get a blank page because I have AdBlock Plus installed. In the source of the page, I can see that it loads a page from `dsnextgen.com` in an `<iframe>`, which includes Google ads.

Comment: as Shaquin said, it shows ads from Google ads, and content is loaded from dsnextgen.com
it shows your domain name because it gets it from your browser with javascript, you can see that by viewing source of the page

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to determine if the ads were actually on that page, or coming from adware on my computer. Seems like the host is putting these ads there.

Comment: As it turns out, the placing of ads on the default error page is in violation of their own Domain Name Registration Agreement. They say that ads will be placed on 404 error pages if you do not set up a custom error page, and that in all cases ads can be disabled via the control panel. They say by not setting custom pages, or disabling the ads, you authorize them to show ads. However, since this is the default error page, customers are not able to customize it, or even disable the ads, like the regular 404 error page, so according to the agreement they are not authorized to show the ads.

Answer (score 4):

Your pages are being served through a proxy running **cloudflare-nginx** which could be catching some 404 errors because slashes in either `/` or `%2F` form cause a different 404 page to be served.

Do you have an `.htaccess` rule that catches all of the possible 404 errors and not just the ones that match your filename scheme? If not, try setting one up. You could also try to run the site in a local server instance and see if the 404 pages behave as expected.

*Edited because I mistakenly took characters produced by `Transfer-encoding: chunked` to be caused by misconfifguration*

Comment: In my .htaccess file I have a 404 error set up in this format: ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php I am aware that the / and % characters cause a different 404 error page to come up, and I'm trying to find out why that is. CloudFlare is basically a caching service, and does not create its own custom error pages like the ones in question. And I'm pretty sure I have it set up to only cache static resources like CSS and image files, not entire pages. So this can't just be some sort of cached error page problem.

Comment: What happens if you include the full URL (including FQDN) in the .htaccess file? You shouldn't have to do that, of course - I'm just curious if it makes a difference.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I tried removing the error page from the .htaccess file altogether, and although my custom error page stopped showing, the one I'm asking about continued to show up.

Comment: Just had a quick look myself, both sets of pages are served through nginx/varnish. Very likely everything originates from the host if not your htaccess. It is the `%2f` causing the issue. Change it to a `/` and you get an even worse result (your htaccess rules are returning full page content for missing png files etc)

Answer (score 3):

If (as you have already determined) your code doesn't generate the error page, then the "mysterious" 404 page comes either from the default websersver configuration (which is presumably controlled by your hosting provider) or *indirectly* from your DNS service (if your webserver redirects your browser to an unregistered domain, for example, then you may be redirected to a page which invites you to buy it).

The most straightforward way IMO to track this down is by using a browser equipped with machinery for tracking redirects (e.g. Firefox with the Firebug extension installed). If the error pages are indeed coming from your domain (and not a misspelling of it), then that implicates the default webserver configuration (and so presumably your hosting provider).

**EDIT:**
Re-reading the above I realize that I should clarify: your DNS service can't simply "redirect" you somewhere. If you find that typing a non-existing domain into your browser redirects you to a page with advertising then you can be fairly sure that it's your **network connectivity provider** that is inspecting your HTTP request, doing a DNS looking on your behalf behind the scenes, and redirecting you.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I meant about my DNS is that I have a domain with one provider, and hosting with another. So my domain is just pointed to my web hosting account.

Comment: This is not a case of the ISP redirecting non-existing pages to another page, like is sometimes the case. I don't get pages like this for any other website.

Comment: Also, I'm sure the pages are coming from my domain. If you see the ads on that page, it has my domain at the top. Copying-and-pasting that domain into the address bar takes you to my website, so it's not misspelled.